# UnsupportedOperation: can't do nonzero end-relative seeks : Python - PyPDF2

Tags: python, pypdf

Can you guys fix the problem? I'm unable to read an arabic PDF file. I don't know what is the issue. Thanks

```
import PyPDF2

def main():

   with   open("arabic_text.pdf", encoding='utf-8') as pdfFile:
       pdfRead = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)
       output = PdfFileWriter()

   for m in range(pdfRead.getNumPages()):
       page = pdfRead.getPage(m)
       pageContent = page.extractText()
       print(pageContent)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 9):

Open the file with rb mode for the usage in PDF format. Example:

```
with open("arabic_text.pdf", 'rb'):
```